# jquery vs native browser javascript performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I know that jQuery's main purpose is not to optimize performance.
But I made this simple test, and I find the difference quite big ( jQuery is ~95% slower... )

```
(jQuery)
    var i = 10000;
    while (i--) {
      $('body').css('min-width', i + '1px');
    }

(native javascript)
    var i = 10000;
    while (i--) {
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style['min-width'] = i + '1px';
    }
```

http://jsperf.com/333444/2

Why is there so big difference?

Comment: try with `document.body`

Comment: Caching the element before the loop makes negligible difference, so it's definitely within the `css()` function.

Comment: Well, the culprit is the `.css()` wrapper which is using extensive code behind the scenes. I don't think it's a big deal, jQuery is meant to be easy to use and cross browser rather that fast, reminds me of the difference between C and C#. If you're worried about efficiency, use plain JavaScript.

Comment: Is this question considered to be not constructive!?